# How to replace selected lines with the plugins api

Tags: c#, notepad++

I want to create a plugin that is to be called with selected text. The plugins should manipulate the text and replace it with what a new content.

I've written all the logic for this but now I need the plumbing to make this into a plugins.  Anny hints on what part of the api I need to use to accomplish this?

And I'm aware of http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Plugin_Development which neither tells how to retrieve the selected text nor how to replace it.

Comment: Google "create notepad++ plugin". First link is to the notepad++ site which has sample code.

Comment: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Plugin_Development#How_to_develop_a_plugin has a "C# template"

Comment: Not really a good pointer to what I want to do Marc.  I understand the template which is for 2010 but it does not do what I want to do

Comment: why not just use the replace feature? Ctrl+H

Comment: The C# template has examples for calling `ScintillaReplaceSelection()` to replace a selection through the Scintilla method `SCI_REPLACESEL`, which is documented [here](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html). As the documentation shows, and the C# template has a static message for, there is a `SCI_GETSELTEXT` method. Should just be a matter of using the template to figure out how to use the `SCI_GETSELTEXT` Scintilla message in a manner similar to how they use `SCI_REPLACESEL` message. In short, information closely related to what you want to do is in the template and in the docs.

Comment: Quantic why don't you make this reply an answer?

Comment: Eh, sure I'll take some reputation. I don't feel like it's an actual answer when there's no code or implementation, but whatever.

Answer (score 1):

The C# template has examples for calling `ScintillaReplaceSelection()` to replace a selection through the Scintilla method `SCI_REPLACESEL`, which is documented [here](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html). As the documentation shows, and the C# template has a static message for, there is a `SCI_GETSELTEXT` method. Should just be a matter of using the template to figure out how to use the `SCI_GETSELTEXT` Scintilla message in a manner similar to how they use `SCI_REPLACESEL` message.